# Error when do dzdo "user is not allowed to execute <script> as <user> on <server> "

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

I have 2 linux servers. RHEL 5.11 and RHEL 7.3. And I have a bash script named "deploy.sh" at `/app/deploy/deploy.sh` and `/app2/deploy/deploy.sh`. There is a user group named "deployers" on Centrify and a user who member of this "deployers" group. This user (I'll call it as "deployer") can run `deploy.sh` script with dzdo on first server (5.11 Tikanga) but it cannot run the same script on second server (7.3 Maipo).

The following output is from Tikanga:

```
[deployer@tikanga ~]$ dzdo -u depuser /app/deploy/deploy.sh
Success!

[deployer@tikanga ~]$ ls -la /app/deploy/ | grep deploy
-rwxr-xr-x  1 depuser depuser     4960 Apr 14  2016 deploy.sh

[root@tikanga ~]# cat /etc/sudoers | grep deployers
%deployers ALL=(depuser)   NOPASSWD: /app/deploy/deploy.sh
```

And following output is from Maipo:

```
[deployer@maipo ~]$ dzdo -u depuser /app2/deploy/deploy.sh
Sorry, user deployer is not allowed to execute '/app2/deploy/deploy.sh' as depuser on maipo.

[deployer@maipo ~]$ ls -la /app2/deploy/ | grep deploy
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 depuser depuser  5159 Aug 17 12:22 deploy.sh

[root@maipo ~]# cat /etc/sudoers | grep deployers
%deployers    ALL=(depuser)   NOPASSWD: /app2/deploy/deploy.sh
```

Both of the servers in the domain with Centrify.

Comment: I'd suggest a `chgrp deployers /app2/deploy/deploy.sh`, however, your would lose the added security of requiring a `su`-like call before running the script.

Comment: It does not work. Same error again.

Comment: That dot at the end of the permissions on app2 might suggest SELinux has something to do with this

Comment: I will try disable selinux when i get permit for rebooting the server. Thanks.

Comment: It was not about selinux. It was about Centrıfy user/group rules.